# Dealing with a duplicate question that has been left un-dealt with

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

So I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902909/how-to-make-a-hidden-checkbox-in-php/37902952#37902952) question the other day which I think is a duplicate of (at a minimum and more of this type exist IIRC) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979781/how-can-i-hide-a-checkbox-in-html).

Let's begin by reluctantly forgiving the fact it would seem to have lacked some prior research...

As you can imagine, there were a number of replies quite rapidly since this is a rather simple question.

What I want to know is why this has not yet (or may not ever) end up being closed and/or deleted?

Now if I may digress a little - I find it rather disgusting that easy questions like this are readily up-voted (ok - this one is a bad example but you *know what I mean*), when I sometimes post answers that gain an equivalent rep for something *far more involved* (to say the least) and it leaves me with quite a bitter feeling.

Back to the question at hand and my justifications for why it is a duplicate:

1. The question has nothing to do with PHP - so it is really asking "How to make a hidden checkbox"
2. Making a hidden checkbox, or using a hidden input? Debatable as to what the questioner really needed since it seems he did not know it was an option.
3. In any case, the duplicate exists for: "How to make a hidden checkbox" if I paraphrase "How can I hide a checkbox (in HTML)".

Comment: When you flag or vote to close a question it goes into the Close review queue to be dealt with... at this moment there are about 8k questions in the queue.  This specific question will be handled at some point. I don't see anything really awful about this question for it to be handled urgently.

Comment: I see, I was not aware the queue was that backlogged! I don't want to go off-topic but if I may ask, what happens to the rep earned during the question's lifetime? If I am not mistaken, it will remain so long as the question is never purged?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only lasted for 1 day, so don't get too down here. I am sure meta will effectively nuke it now that we are all casting a discerning eye.

Yes, it is a duplicate, not only by way of presenting the same problem, but the OP in comments even confirms in the one answer that they went with the checkbox and display:none option that the duplicate also presents.

As for why this happens, to be honest, it was probably faster to answer than to find the duplicate, and time is rather important to people. Some people just want to answer and move on, others realize that we should favor quality over quantity and attempt to cultivate instead of littering.

Don't let it get you down or annoyed though, it will just make you jaded. This is just a side effect of the system. If you can come up with ways to make the system more efficient then by all means post it as a discussion to share with the community. Another option would be to get a relevant gold tag badge and dupehammer these types of posts ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer me Travis. And yes, it does make you feel a bit jaded when you see it happen so often. Ah!